# Array buffer IE10 - Typed array constructor argument is invalid

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, canvas

Im using Javascript canvas to change pixels on an image. At some point I need the array buffer to work with the jsfeat.js library.

IE10 tells me that "Typed array constructor argument is invalid" at this line :

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, W, H);
var data_u32 = new Uint32Array(imagedata.data.buffer);
```

When I console.log imagedata.data.buffer, it gives me "undefined" in IE10. In Chrome I have " ArrayBuffer {}".

If i pass the data directly the effect is not working.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: What is `imagedata`? How are you setting it?

Comment: Just a simple ctx.getImageData. I edited myquestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10's `.getImageData` used a CanvasPixelArray rather than the newer Uint32Array.

(Uint32Array was available to IE10, but it wasn't implemented in canvas)

The CanvasPixelArray.data has no `.buffer` property--that's the cause of your error warning.

**Example code to "manually" load imageData into your data_u32.**

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, W, H);

// init the array by size
var data_u32 = new Uint32Array(W*H*4);

// fill the array "manually"
var data=imageData.data;
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data_u32[n]=data[n];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it in my project when i get back to it. I keep you posted if it works !

Comment: It did not for me. Firstly the length of the array has to be `W*H`, because with `var data_u32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);` , `data_u32.length ` equals `imageData.data.length/4` equals `W*H`. then in your code you're refering to an unset `n`. With this respected Im still not getting the result s im expecting. (Im working with jsfeats' canny edge detector)